# Iframe autoresize

Tags: html, iframe, autoresize

I am designing a web page with HTML IFrames
is there a possible way to make the Iframe width and height autoresize and is that compatable with at least (IE,firefox,safari,chrom) ??

please help !

Comment: What do you mean by auto-resize?

Comment: Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/819416/adjust-width-height-of-iframe-to-fit-with-content-in-it

Answer (score 0):

No.

You can manage the width pretty easily, but web pages are flow documents and do not "understand" the concept of height (not easily, at least).

In order to do something like this, you'll have to use javascript.  To make your javascript cross-browser compatible as easily as possible, you should use a framework such as [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

There are several questions here about resizing content to height using jQuery [like this one.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838137/jquery-change-height-based-on-browser-size-resize)

Answer (score 0):

in onload of iframe call a function where you set the height , width of the iframe .

```
    <iframe name="preview" id="preview" width="450" height="450"    onLoad="iframeResize();"></iframe>

    <script>
        function iframeResize () {
            document.getElementById('preview').height = SOMEVALUE
            document.getElementById('preview').width = SOMEVALUE
        }  
    </script>
```