# I need help in a iframe

Tags: iframe

I do not have much knowledgement of HTML, CSS, etc. and I work on a Wordpress website.

My question is how do I make an iframe like in this website http://www.stadtrundfahrten-muenchen.de/de/startseite/#top  when I click in the order button!?

I have a similar website with boxes and a button saying "order now", in fact the iframe should be equal to that website because its the same ticketing provider. They sent me the iframe link but cannot make like that website!
can anyone help me with this or tips?

regards

Answer (score 0):

The website you mentioned does not use iframe anywhere. If you are trying to set dynamic size of an iframe please reefer here: [how-to-set-iframe-size-dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7317781/how-to-set-iframe-size-dynamically)
It would be good if you can post the iframe you are trying to implement

Answer (score 0):

ok here it is the code:

You vcan visit the website http://hmk.no are the boxes in frontpage, the one which says book now.

And i would like a iframe or window transparent like here in this site:

http://www.stadtrundfahrten-muenchen.de/de/startseite/#top

[https://office.instantticketing.com/pit/webshop/widgetconfig?key=khaxfcarjhtso4h9lubk5ywwcp21386707097031'>]

Comment: <iframe style='height: 335px; width: 780px; margin:0; padding:0; border:0;' allowtransparency='true' src='https://office.instantticketing.com/pit/webshop/widgetconfig?key=khaxfcarjhtso4h9lubk5ywwcp21386707097031'></iframe>