# How to resize div with height not fixed of an iframe inner

Tags: html

I have that structure in my code. Height of my iframe is not fixed, it oscillate.

```
<div>
<iframe></iframe>
</div>
```

I want that the div height to be iframe height.

I thought in

```
<div height=100%> .. </div>
```

but it doesnt works

Sorry for by bad English and Thanks!

My code:

```
<div style="position: relative;
  height:1000px;  ">

    <iframe frameborder="0"  scrollable="no" src="/driv.php" style="position: absolute;
    top: 0; 
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;"></iframe>
```

EDIT:

```
<div class="mydiv" style="position: relative;
height:1000px ">

    <iframe class="myif"frameborder="0"  scrollable="no" src="/pilotos2.php" style="position: absolute;
    top: 0; 
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;"></iframe>
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"> 
$('.mydiv').css('height', $('.myif').height()+'px');
</script>
```

I tried that and doesnt works..

Comment: post your whole code if you want help

Comment: Sorry, here it is

Comment: I have 1000px of height, but this param is what i want modify with iframe height

Comment: Possible duplicate of [make iframe height dynamic based on content inside- JQUERY/Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9162933/make-iframe-height-dynamic-based-on-content-inside-jquery-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this

HTML

```
<div class="parent">
<iframe></iframe>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.parent{
   overflow: auto;
   float:left;
}
```

Edit:
This will not work for iframes. Check here for solution: [make iframe height dynamic based on content inside- JQUERY/Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9162933/make-iframe-height-dynamic-based-on-content-inside-jquery-javascript)

Comment: Maybe because I wrote position: relative; also, because I need write that

Comment: You also need to remove the fixed height declaration you have. This code will allow the parent div to have the same height and width as its children. What are you trying to achieve here? A width of 100% and the height the same as the child or the height and width the same as the child?

Comment: I removed fixed height, I only wrote what you send and position:relative.
Im trying that parent has 100% of the height of his children

Comment: Okay, I was wrong. It appears this type of solution will not work for iframe (I tested it using one div inside of another). You're looking for something like this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9162933/make-iframe-height-dynamic-based-on-content-inside-jquery-javascript

Comment: Or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7317781/how-to-set-iframe-size-dynamically

Answer (score 0):

If you want the outer div to inherit the height of the iframe, do not set a height on the div. It will automatically adjust to the height of the iframe. Try this by setting `height=100px` on the iframe.

Setting `height:100%;` on the div will only cause the div to expand the full height of it's parent.

Comment: I can set a fixed height. Because it deppends of the case. Maybe the height can be 100px or 2480px..