# How to modify CSS via JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to get the screen and modify the css styles of my box.
Thats my code

```
if ($('.content').height() > $(window).height() - 100) {
    $('.content').css("max-height", $(window).height() - 100);
}
```

Now I want to set the max height of the .content box lower than the height of my screen size.
If my content box is higher than my screen size, the css should set de max height and change the overflow to auto.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/838137/jquery-change-height-based-on-browser-size-resize) might help you mate...

Comment: Any errors you're getting?

Comment: no error.
e.g. my screen sice is 924px and my .content looks higher and is out of the screen, but its only 608px high

Comment: @ChrisserMadethis please read @Vandesh's answer, the fewer `$` you have in your code the better. Your script so far has 4, and it could have 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you could do this -

```
var content = $(".content");
// Cache the height in variables, no need to access DOM again and again
var screenHeight = $(window).height();
var contentHeight = content.height();
if(contentHeight>windowHeight-100){
  content.css("overflow","auto"); // Note - this will change it for the current instance of the page and NOT in your CSS file
  content.css("max-height",(windowHeight-100) + "px");      
}
```

You can also combine the above two css properties in one single statement (written separately for explanation) -

```
content.css({"max-height":(windowHeight-100)+"px","overflow":"auto"});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use the max height value along with `px`.

```
if ( $('.content').height() > ($(window).height() - 100) ) {
    $('.content').css("max-height", ( $(window).height() - 100 ) + "px" )
                 .css("overflow","auto");
}
```

This would resolve you issue.

Answer (score 0):

Do this -

```
var maxHeight = $(window).height() - 100;
if ($('.content').height() > maxHeight) {
    $('.content').css({"max-height": maxHeight, overflow: "auto"});
}
```

Comment: hm i've seen that jquery writes nothing into the html

Answer (score 0):

Use unit "px"

```
 $('.content').css("max-height", ($(window).height() - 100)+"px");
```